# autocomplete error coming in jsp/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

//**index.jsp**

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>JSP page</title>
<script="text/javascript">
$(function() {
// subscribe to the keydown event
$('#text1').keydown(function(e) {
    // when a key is pressed check if its code was 9 (TAB)
    if (e.which == 9) {
        // if TAB was pressed send an AJAX request
        // to the server passing it the currently 
        // entered value in the first textbox
        $.ajax({
            url: '/someservlet/',// i have created a servlet named as someservlet
            type: 'POST',
            data: { value: $(this).val() },
            success: function(result) {
                // when the AJAX succeeds update the value of the 
                // second textbox using the result returned by the server
                // In this example we suppose that the servlet returns
                // the following JSON: {"foo":"bar"}
                $('#text2').val(result.foo);
            }
        });    
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<input type="text" id="text1" name="firsttextbox"/>
<input type="text" id="text2" name="secondtextbox"/>
<body>
```

//**do post() someservlet**

```
String dd = request.getParameter("firsttextbox"); 
String json = new Gson().toJson(options);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Do i need to import any js file inside head block? Can anyone tell me where i am wrong? While compiling i am getting the jsper...error. Same code is working in fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JLJ3f/

While compiling in netbeans, i am getting error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you are using jquery functions but you don have jquery library in your html page,
in fiddle you can import it in your left frame, under chose framework menu,

info:following are the different CDN

- Google Ajax API CDN (Also supports SSL via HTTPS)
    o http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
    o Google Ajax CDN Documentation
- Microsoft CDN (Also supports SSL via HTTPS)
    o http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
    o Ajax CDN Announcement, Microsoft Ajax CDN Documentation
- jQuery CDN (via Media Temple)
    o http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js Minified version
    o http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js Source version

so you can add it through `<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
    or
download it locally and link it to your html page

Comment: thanks a lot run for your answer...i will come back to you soon

Comment: can you please tell me what modification should i do in servlet? Just by entering some data in first textbox, i want to autofill second textbox where data is coming from servlet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923638/how-to-return-multiple-json-objects-from-java-servlet-using-one-ajax-request hope this will help you